# reCAPTCHA validation failed, suspected as abusive usage

Tags: recaptcha

a customer of ours has been experiencing problems with ReCaptcha v3 for a few days now.

When they want to send a message themselves via a contact form, they get the following error message: Invalid Form - ReCaptcha validation failed, suspected as abusive usage.

When we try the same form via another computer/network, the form works normally. Even when we fill in the form via our phone on 4G/5G, everything just works. Should we be concerned? Or may the problem occur to them because they are on their own website every day.